# Springboot + hibernate Can't cast entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to solve my problem from 2 hours but I completly have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

So, I'm using springboot + hibernate in simple app. But when I'm trying to get data about employee from DB and show it on main page - my entity is null.

I tried to check everything what I know to check, my components using annotations good, in services @Service, in controllers @Controller and if i'm using service in my controller I'm using @Autowired.

Problem is that, when I'm trying to get Employee from DB in main method it is possible I can do this. But when I want to show it on html page in console I have this error message:

```
vt.db.model.entity.Employee cannot be cast to vt.db.model.entity.Employee
```

I tried to check if the entity is created with simple overriding toString() and yes, I can see there data of this entity. But if i try to cast object from criteria list to this entity - i got null.

Here is code:

My service:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    private IEmployee emp;


    public EmployeeService() {
        this.emp = new EmployeeDao();
    }


    public Employee getUserByEvidenceNumberLogin(String login) {
        Employee employee = this.emp.findByLogin(login);

        return employee;
    }




}
```

DAO method to get employee from db:

```
    public Employee findByLogin(String login) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = null;
        Employee employee = null;

        try {
            criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("empEvidenceNumber", login));

            employee = (Employee) criteria.list().get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }

        return employee;
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired private EmployeeService emp = new EmployeeService();




    @RequestMapping(value = "/a/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminIndex(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        String username = authentication.getName();
        session.setAttribute("username", username);

        Employee employee = emp.getUserByEvidenceNumberLogin(username);

        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);

        return "a/index";
    }
}
```

And my full entity class:

```
    package vt.db.model.entity;

import vt.db.model.entity.base.Entity;

public class Employee extends Entity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1400760321767476971L;
    private String empFirstName;
    private String empPassword;
    private String empRole;
    private String empLastName;
    private String empBirthDate;
    private String empAvatar;
    private Integer empDepartmentId;
    private Integer empEnabled;
    private Integer empPositionId;
    private Integer empManagerId;
    private Integer empIsManager;
    private String empEvidenceNumber;
    private Double empAreaOfWork;
    private Integer empWorkingHoursPerDay;
    private String empFirstWorkDay;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return empFirstName;
    }
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }
    public Employee(String empFirstName, String empLastName, String empBirthDate, String empAvatar,
            Integer empDepartmentId, Integer empPositionId, Integer empManagerId, Integer empIsManager,
            String empEvidenceNumber, Double empAreaOfWork, Integer empWorkingHoursPerDay, String empFirstWorkDay) {
        super();
        this.empFirstName = empFirstName;
        this.empLastName = empLastName;
        this.empBirthDate = empBirthDate;
        this.empAvatar = empAvatar;
        this.empDepartmentId = empDepartmentId;
        this.empPositionId = empPositionId;
        this.empManagerId = empManagerId;
        this.empIsManager = empIsManager;
        this.empEvidenceNumber = empEvidenceNumber;
        this.empAreaOfWork = empAreaOfWork;
        this.empWorkingHoursPerDay = empWorkingHoursPerDay;
        this.empFirstWorkDay = empFirstWorkDay;
    }
    public Employee(String empPassword, String empRole, String empFirstName, String empLastName, String empBirthDate, String empAvatar,
            Integer empDepartmentId, Integer empPositionId, Integer empManagerId, Integer empIsManager,
            String empEvidenceNumber, Double empAreaOfWork, Integer empWorkingHoursPerDay, String empFirstWorkDay) {
        super();
        this.empPassword = empPassword;
        this.empRole = empRole;
        this.empFirstName = empFirstName;
        this.empLastName = empLastName;
        this.empBirthDate = empBirthDate;
        this.empAvatar = empAvatar;
        this.empDepartmentId = empDepartmentId;
        this.empPositionId = empPositionId;
        this.empManagerId = empManagerId;
        this.empIsManager = empIsManager;
        this.empEvidenceNumber = empEvidenceNumber;
        this.empAreaOfWork = empAreaOfWork;
        this.empWorkingHoursPerDay = empWorkingHoursPerDay;
        this.empFirstWorkDay = empFirstWorkDay;
    }
    public Employee(String empPassword, String empRole, Integer empEnabled, String empFirstName, String empLastName, String empBirthDate, String empAvatar,
            Integer empDepartmentId, Integer empPositionId, Integer empManagerId, Integer empIsManager,
            String empEvidenceNumber, Double empAreaOfWork, Integer empWorkingHoursPerDay, String empFirstWorkDay) {
        super();
        this.empPassword = empPassword;
        this.empRole = empRole;
        this.empEnabled = empEnabled;
        this.empFirstName = empFirstName;
        this.empLastName = empLastName;
        this.empBirthDate = empBirthDate;
        this.empAvatar = empAvatar;
        this.empDepartmentId = empDepartmentId;
        this.empPositionId = empPositionId;
        this.empManagerId = empManagerId;
        this.empIsManager = empIsManager;
        this.empEvidenceNumber = empEvidenceNumber;
        this.empAreaOfWork = empAreaOfWork;
        this.empWorkingHoursPerDay = empWorkingHoursPerDay;
        this.empFirstWorkDay = empFirstWorkDay;
    }


    public String getEmpFirstName() {
        return this.empFirstName;
    }
    public void setEmpFirstName(String empFirstName) {
        this.empFirstName = empFirstName;
    }
    public String getEmpLastName() {
        return this.empLastName;
    }
    public void setEmpLastName(String empLastName) {
        this.empLastName = empLastName;
    }
    public String getEmpBirthDate() {
        return this.empBirthDate;
    }
    public void setEmpBirthDate(String empBirthDate) {
        this.empBirthDate = empBirthDate;
    }
    public String getEmpAvatar() {
        return this.empAvatar;
    }
    public void setEmpAvatar(String empAvatar) {
        this.empAvatar = empAvatar;
    }
    public Integer getEmpDepartmentId() {
        return this.empDepartmentId;
    }
    public void setEmpDepartmentId(Integer empDepartmentId) {
        this.empDepartmentId = empDepartmentId;
    }
    public Integer getEmpPositionId() {
        return this.empPositionId;
    }
    public void setEmpPositionId(Integer empPositionId) {
        this.empPositionId = empPositionId;
    }
    public Integer getEmpManagerId() {
        return this.empManagerId;
    }
    public void setEmpManagerId(Integer empManagerId) {
        this.empManagerId = empManagerId;
    }
    public Integer getEmpIsManager() {
        return this.empIsManager;
    }
    public void setEmpIsManager(Integer empIsManager) {
        this.empIsManager = empIsManager;
    }
    public String getEmpEvidenceNumber() {
        return this.empEvidenceNumber;
    }
    public void setEmpEvidenceNumber(String empEvidenceNumber) {
        this.empEvidenceNumber = empEvidenceNumber;
    }
    public Double getEmpAreaOfWork() {
        return this.empAreaOfWork;
    }
    public void setEmpAreaOfWork(Double empAreaOfWork) {
        this.empAreaOfWork = empAreaOfWork;
    }
    public Integer getEmpWorkingHoursPerDay() {
        return this.empWorkingHoursPerDay;
    }
    public void setEmpWorkingHoursPerDay(Integer empWorkingHoursPerDay) {
        this.empWorkingHoursPerDay = empWorkingHoursPerDay;
    }
    public String getEmpFirstWorkDay() {
        return this.empFirstWorkDay;
    }
    public void setEmpFirstWorkDay(String empFirstWorkDay) {
        this.empFirstWorkDay = empFirstWorkDay;
    }
    public String getEmpPassword() {
        return empPassword;
    }
    public void setEmpPassword(String empPassword) {
        this.empPassword = empPassword;
    }
    public String getEmpRole() {
        return empRole;
    }
    public void setEmpRole(String empRole) {
        this.empRole = empRole;
    }
    public Integer getEmpEnabled() {
        return empEnabled;
    }
    public void setEmpEnabled(Integer empEnabled) {
        this.empEnabled = empEnabled;
    }
}
```

Employee entity extends Entity class which has simple id field and use Serializable interface. Each entity has own auto generated serialVersionUID.

For clarity I forgot to tell at the beginning, my service is working fine because I tried to display on main page simple string metod and it works. Problem is in casting in DAO class in this line:

```
employee = (Employee) criteria.list().get(0);
```

But I have no idea why and what is wrong because always when I did something with hibernate I use this cast and it works good.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Exception casting to the same exact class  means that they have been loaded my different ClassLoaders.

Comment: So what I need to do?

Comment: Check your deployment and see how it is loaded. The issue is most likely not in the code.

Comment: I have no idea what to do I cant find any mistakes...

Comment: Show how you are deploying and running your app. Maybe we can help.

Comment: I'm running app in eclipse normally just start app as springboot. I dont understand why when i'm not trying show this entity in controller, just in simple main class with console I have no problems and it works. Even I tried create new project and just copy sources, with new workspace and still the same.